# Does the source champion count as a "nearby ally"?

Tags: league-of-legends

Certain items have passives that say they affect "nearby allies", but would these passives affect the source champion themselves?

For example, [Locket of the Iron Solari](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Locket_of_the_Iron_Solari) has such a unique passive, Legion:

> UNIQUE – LEGION: Nearby allied minions and champions gain +15 magic resist (1100 range).

It does not specify whether this passive affects the source champion or not. It could be interpreted that since the source champion is allied and also nearby (in a sense), it does affect them. One could also assume that since it is not explicitly stated, it does not affect them.

**So does the source champion count as a "nearby ally", or is it not so?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From experience, yes, the effect applies to yourself as well as nearby allies. You can see the buff appear in your buff bar the same way it appears in nearby allies' buff bar.

To expand a bit, there's been a "feature" in the game for as long as I can remember where two people can have the same aura item and be affected by it twice, once for their item, and once for the single other teammate's. This is because it is applied as an aura to your allies and as a separate buff, though with the same name and stats, to yourself. (Thanks to @Dragonrage for pointing this out.)

More on the [Locket of the Iron Solari wiki page](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Locket_of_the_Iron_Solari), in the trivia section.

Comment: Ahh but it's a different buff

Comment: @indeed I added a bit more in terms of recorded proof. For the most part, this is experience speaking. The best way to fact check me is to get into the game and build only the Aegis of the Legion and look at the value of your bonus MR.

Comment: The source says "nearby allies units have increased Magic Resist." Other units say "This unit has increased Magic Resist."

Comment: @indeed, nukeforum is correct that the Legion will effect the holder, however it is incorrect to say the aura effects the holder. It appears to be coded that the aura instead gives you a unique passive with the same stats, as another ally can get the item and the unique aura from their item will effect you.